# How to add, insert and update JSON value into MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-json

I have one JSON column ('posts') in MYSQL table . When somebody posts something i want to add this data to this column like this  `{ "status": "active", "id": "112" }`

I can  only do this  "`UPDATE users set  posts = ? WHERE id = ? "` 
But it deletes and writes data into 'posts' . I need to append data to the beggining of json data.
My question is simple example of adding json data and updating data (for example where id='112' status='archived')

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't do that. Create a table for posts.

Comment: As Salman A said - don't do it. It smells! But assuming you are ignoring his advice, please  update your question to include the CREATE TABLE statement, an example of what a row looks like and what you want it to be after applying your update.